# Problem with pandas loc, which can't find date value in index

Tags: python, pandas

I have next test data CSV file

```
time,value
2018-09-17,0.0002897
2018-09-16,0.0002955
2018-09-15,0.0002862
2018-09-14,0.0003054
2018-09-13,0.000312
2018-09-12,0.0003467
2018-09-11,0.0003433
2018-09-10,0.0003287
2018-09-09,0.0003355
2018-09-08,0.0003288
```

When I run next code in python console, pandas in result can't find the first row in the index (2018-09-17). You can see an error message in below transcript

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s1 = pd.read_csv("series1.csv")
>>> s1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(s1['time'])
>>> s1.set_index('time', inplace=True)
>>> s1
               value
time
2018-09-17  0.000290
2018-09-16  0.000296
2018-09-15  0.000286
2018-09-14  0.000305
2018-09-13  0.000312
2018-09-12  0.000347
2018-09-11  0.000343
2018-09-10  0.000329
2018-09-09  0.000336
2018-09-08  0.000329
>>> s1.loc['2018-09-16']
               value
time
2018-09-16  0.000296
>>> s1.loc['2018-09-17']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1506, in _has_valid_type
    error()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1501, in error
    axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [2018-09-17] is not in the [index]'
```

I repeated this test on Linux and Windows, the same result. On both, Windows and Linux pandas version is 0.22.0

Comment: What is `print (df.index[:10])` and `print (df.index[:10].tolist())` ?

Comment: `>>> print(s1.index[:10])`
`DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-17', '2018-09-16', '2018-09-15', '2018-09-14',
               '2018-09-13', '2018-09-12', '2018-09-11', '2018-09-10',
               '2018-09-09', '2018-09-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)`

Comment: `>>> print(s1.index[:10].tolist())`
`[Timestamp('2018-09-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('201
8-09-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-09-09 00:00:0
0'), Timestamp('2018-09-08 00:00:00')]`

Comment: It seems nice, no idea why not working.

Answer (score 0):

I posted bug report to pandas-dev and they responded, that this bug is fixed in pandas 0.24.2